# does SQL Server 2019 developer edition support SSISDB and SQL Job agent?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL server 2019 developer edition in my home laptop but i can not see SSISDB database and SQL Job agent. Does SQL Server 2019 support both feature?

Comment: Are you sure you installed DE rather than Express Edition? DE supports both. The SSISDB catalog needs to be created by right-clicking the Integrations Services Catalogs node in SSMS object explorer. The SQL Server Agent Service should already be installed.

Comment: yes, i have installed DE edition.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition has both of those features, and is the same as Enterprise Edition.  SQL Server Agent is installed by default.  SSISDB isn't created by default.  You need to create one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: It looks as below]

it is now showing to me.
SELECT @@Version

Result:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0  (Build 18363: )

Comment: You can accept this as the answer.  You installed Express Edition, or you might have both, but you're connected to Express Edition.

Comment: If you do have both installed, it may be the Developer Edition is installed as the default instance. In that case, you can connect specifying only the host name or '.'.